# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable with StackingClassifier

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

Today I'm coding a Stacking classifier, compound by 3 differents models already fitted.
But when I would like to obtain the `precision_recall_curve`, I obtain two types of error.

If I use a SVC for `final_estimator`:

> This 'StackingClassifier' has no attribute 'predict_proba'

If I use a Logistic Regression for the `final_estimator`:

> 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

This is the code :

```
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier

cl = [('SVC', svc), ('RFC', RFC), ('KNN', KNN)] # the different model already trained

stack_model = StackingClassifier(estimators = cl, final_estimator = LogisticRegression()).fit(X_train, y_train)

score=roc_auc_score(y_test,stack_model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]) 
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, stack_model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1], pos_label="1") #Where the numpy error appeared
```

The `X_train`, `X_test` are:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

The `y_train` and `y_test` are:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I learned many topics corresponding to the `numpy.ndarray` error, but not in this case. Do you any idea as to how to avoid this error?

Thank you very much for your future help!

Comment: SVC doesn't have `predict_proba` unless you set `probability=True`.  For logistic regression, please provide the full error traceback (edit it into the question).

Comment: If you either get an `attribute error`, or a not-callable error, the object (variable) is the wrong class that operation.  `xxx()` assumes `xxx` is a function (or method); it is the wrong thing to do with an array.

Comment: Also provide the full error message